# COGNOS REPORT STUDIO grouping

Tags: business-intelligence, cognos

I am new to cognos.

I have created a list report with the following columns...

```
ID,Forename,Surname,ProductCode,ProductTitle
```

I have two value prompts (drop down boxes) for the user to pick two product titles.

I want my list report to only display when a `Customer` has purchased both products. At the moment I have all `Product1` all `Product2` and all where `Product1` and `Product2` are relating to one `customer`.

I have then grouped `by ID,Forename,Surname`.

I have tried doing counts and running-counts but can't seem to come up with a solution.

Any advise would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filters:

```
[ProductCode] = ?product1? || [ProductCode] = ?product2?
count(distinct [ProductCode] for [ID]) = 2
```

The first filter limits the rows to just ones where the product matches either prompt. The second counts up the distinct product codes for each customer and excludes customers that don't have two.

Comment: I in fact wanted where it was only 2 products per person and not showing the people who had only 1.  this doesn't seem to be working. Can you advise if it needs to be different to display where the customers have purchased both products.

Comment: You need to be more specific. "doesn't seem to be working" is not enough information to help you. These filters should only show people who have purchased both products.

Comment: Apologies, the report still seems to be showing everything (people with one product or two products). When the value prompts were created I created a new query for each variable and added the qualification title to the queries. I have placed the filters in query 1. Please let me know if you need anything further.

Comment: Hey all, sorry to drag this up again but i have managed to work this back into my priority pile. I still have the problem where by the result set returned when the above filters have been applied is any id which matches either of the product codes rather than both. Any further help on this would be really really appreciated